# How to prepare string for GET

Tags: php, json, get

I'm writing API that will be used as communication between two servers.
I'm using GET via Curl and json.

My client is sending user agent like

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1

How can I send string like that via GET request?
I guess I need to clean it somehow or encrypt in some format that can be turned into original on server side.

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: it has to be encoded to be part of the url of the GET request ... see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are searching for [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode)    and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode)

Comment: I would say that they are not comparable because they are existing for different purposes. As I do understand `urlencode()` it escapes all "illegal" URL parameters so that your PHP script is possible to receive it as an $_GET parameter. In an `base64_encode()`d string there are i.e. "=" contained which would have to be escaped for your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your CURL request to contain a custom header, you can use the `curl_setopt` function with the `CURLOPT_HEADER` option to stipulate your custom user-agent, see

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

(I don't really see the reason to try and transfer that kind of data as a GET parameter when you have a more traditional place for it. If you're writing an API, you'd better stick to some basic ways of doing things :) )